# How can I split a range into smaller "chunks?"

Tags: matlab, vector

I am using the `imfindcircles()` algorithm to identify circles with radii in a certain range, such as `[20 80]`.

However, the algorithm is more efficient when working with smaller ranges, so

```
imfindcircles(IMG, [20 51]);
imfindcircles(IMG, [51 80]);
```

is more efficient than

```
imfindcircles(IMG, [20 80]);
```

My question is this: how can I break the range (`[20 80]` in this case) into n "segments" I can feed into a `for` loop or other such construct to automate this?

Desired output:

```
splitFunc( [20 80], 2)
    % outputs [ [20 50] [51 80] ]
splitFunc( [20 80], 3)
    % outputs [ [20 40] [41 60] [61 80] ]
```

and so on.

I have looked at using `linspace()` and `reshape()`, but I do not think they will do what I need.

**Edit:** This is my modification of the accepted answer's code, to deal with some boundary problems:

```
minRadius = 20;
maxRadius = 80;
n = 4; % number of chunks to split range into

grid = floor(linspace(minRadius,maxRadius,n+1));
grid(end) = grid(end);

rangeVec = zeros(2,n-1);

% Split the range into n chunks
for i=1:length(grid)-1
    rangeVec(1,i) = grid(i);
    rangeVec(2,i) = grid(i+1);
end

% Now, increment the start point of each range chunk, to prevent overlap
for i=2:length(rangeVec)
    rangeVec(1,i) = rangeVec(1,i) + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use `linspace` I think you just need to more careful, make sure you get only integers and be careful about boundary conditions.

```
minValue = 20;
maxValue = 80;
Chunks = 9;
grid = floor(linspace(minValue,maxValue,Chunks));
grid(end) = grid(end)+1; % fixes the end boundary condition
for id=1:length(space)-1
    [grid(id),grid(id+1)-1]
    % Do your seperation
end
```